# Navigation Bar - Li Hover - Click On Link

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav, navigationbar

Problem with a navigation bar (again).
You can only click on the li when you hover over the center of the li, not on the top of the bottom... I tried to switch the LIs and the As, so:

```
<a><li></li></a>
```

But that didn't work too...

Thank You,
HydraCles

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rksyqf37/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="nav">
        <a href="li1.html"><li title="li1">li1</a></li>
        <a href="li2.html"><li title="li2">li2</a></li>
        <a href="li3.html"><li title="li3">li3</a></li>
        <a href="li4.html"><li title="li4">li4</a></li>         
        <a href="li5.html"><li title="li5">li5</a></li>
        <a href="li6.html"><li title="li6">li6</a></li>
        <a href="li7.html"><li title="li7">li7</a></li>
        <a href="li8.html"><li title="li8">li8</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/97f4b171db68d6ef1836c8fcb9a1c1a3/oi8jcug/xIcn5vql3/tumblr_static_aajc47nn2ds8c0k004gskoo0c.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    font-size: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    height: 50px;
}

#nav li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#nav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You are ending the anchor before you end the <li> element. Swap the closing tags around and your current code will work fine, but change the hover behaviour to the anchor, since in this case it is the parent element.

Comment: See in my fiddle how it works fine because i changed the HTML syntax. it its still not working for u update another filddle with your problem and give us to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before your HTML tags `<a>` and `<li>` are wrongly placed.
But for your first problem, you just have to add `display: inline-block;` to your `a` selector.
btw, remove the padding from the `li` and add it to your `a`.

You cannot wrapp `li` tags with other tags. `li` tags should allways be the `ul` or `ol` direct following tags.

And you couldn't click around your `a`s because it's an inline tag by default. That's why you must add the inline-block property which allows the best from inline and the best from block ;)

[upated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rksyqf37/5/)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <a href="li1.html"><li title="li1">li1</li></a>
    <a href="li2.html"><li title="li2">li2</li></a>
    <a href="li3.html"><li title="li3">li3</li></a>
    <a href="li4.html"><li title="li4">li4</li></a>         
    <a href="li5.html"><li title="li5">li5</li></a>
    <a href="li6.html"><li title="li6">li6</li></a>
    <a href="li7.html"><li title="li7">li7</li></a>
    <a href="li8.html"><li title="li8">li8</li></a>
</ul>
```

> The Closing tags were wrong it should be `</li>` followed by `</a>` but it was **`</a></li>`**

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rksyqf37/1/)

Answer (score 1):

We can use Jquery to add a click event for the LI items as below.
For this to work add the anchor tags within the LI items

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#nav li:has(a)").click(function() {
         window.location = $("a:first",this).attr("href");
     });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But I'm not ready for JQuery etc yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li title="li1"><a href="li1.html">li1</a></li>
 <li title="li2"><a href="li2.html">li2</a></li>
 <li title="li3"><a href="li3.html">li3</a></li>
 <li title="li4"><a href="li4.html">li4</a></li>

</ul>
```

You have wrong html: `<a><li></a></li>` instead of `<li><a></a></li>`.